# EditorConfig/vim: tab character lost if alone on line

Tags: vim, editorconfig

I'm using the [vim plugin](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim) to [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) with these settings:

```
let g:EditorConfig_exclude_patterns = ['fugitive://.*']
let g:EditorConfig_core_mode = "external_command"
let g:EditorConfig_preserve_formatoptions = 1
```

I'm on Ubuntu and installed EditorConfig with:

```
sudo apt-get install editorconfig
```

I'm editing a source code file in an open source project that has lines like this (">" indicates tab character):

```
// code
>
// code
>   
// code
```

I find that when I save the file, EditorConfig is stripping out the tab characters that are alone on a line.

```
// code

// code

// code
```

The .editorconfig for the project looks like this:

```
root = true

[*]
indent_style = tab
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

# npm is using 2 spaces when modifying package.json
[package.json]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

I've looked through the EditorConfig documentation but I can't find a way to keep the stray tab characters.

I understand that these stray tab characters are meaninless and the code is actually cleaner without them, but I don't want to make extra edits to files that I am trying to patch.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I think this is due to the `trim_trailing_whitespace = true` in your config. "Trailing" does not necessarily mean that there's actual characters before the whitespace in a line.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I removed that and it stopped removing the tab characters.

Comment: Is there a way I can have a global setting to override this setting in the repo I'm making changes to?

Comment: Great! I've added an answer for you to accept; I hope I've also addressed your second question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the

```
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

from your config. "Trailing" does not necessarily mean that there's actual characters before the whitespace in a line; it also affects all-whitespace lines, too.

#### Applying for certain projects / repositories only

If you need different settings for different directories, you'd use `:autocmd` inside Vim to vary the option values, or use a full-blown *local vimrc* plugin.

I don't know much about EditorConfig, but its home page reads:

> When opening a file, EditorConfig plugins look for a file named `.editorconfig` in the directory of the opened file and in every parent directory.

So, if you need to configure this differently for one repository, just put such file into the repository's root dir, and reconfigure the `trim_trailing_whitespace` option there.